# Improve and beautify Typescript array property aggregation code snippet

Tags: arrays, typescript, properties, aggregation

My question will be so simple : 
how would you have written this simple code snippet ?

```
    get global(): number {
      if (this.subs) {
        let globalReturn: number = 0;
          this.subs.forEach(tps => {
          globalReturn+= tps.countProperty;
        })
        return globalReturn;
      }
      else return 0;
    }
```

Thanks for your opinions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
get global(): number {
  return !this.subs
    ? 0
    : this.subs.reduce((sum, { countProperty }) => sum + countProperty, 0)
}
```

Comment: Wow always impressed how code is pretty with that kind of concepts ! thank you --> documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Added the link for you :-)